# "NotImplementedError: >= and <= don't work with 0." I'm performing sentiment analysis using SVM kernel that i tried coding myself

Tags: python, machine-learning, svm, sentiment-analysis

I am performing sentiment analysis on this text page using SVM kernel that i tried coding myself but upon running this code i happened to run on this error message that i cant quite solve.

Would really appreciate if somebody could give me a clue on what the error is about cause im quite new to python programming

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import time
from sklearn import svm
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class SVM:
    
    def init(self, learning_rate = 0.001, lambda_param = 0.01, n_iters = 1000):
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.lambda_param = lambda_param
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        self.w = None
        self.b = None
        
    def fit(self,x ,y):
        y_ = np.where(y <= 0, -1, 1)
        n_samples, n_features = X.shape
        
        self.w = np.zeros(n_features)
        self.b = 0
        
        for _ in range(self.niters):
            for idx, x_i in enumarate(X):
                condition = y_[idx] * (np.dot(x_i, self.w) - self.b) >= 1
                if condition:
                    self.w -= self.lr * (2 * self.lambda_param * self.w)
                else:
                    self.w -= self.lr * (2 * self.lambda_param * self.w - np.dot(x_i, y_[idx]))
                    self.b -= self.lr * y_[idx]
    
    def predict(self, x):
        linear_output = np.dot(X, self.w) - self.b
        return np.sign(linear_output)
    

# train Data
trainData = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vasistareddy/sentiment_analysis/master/data/train.csv")

# test Data
testData = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Vasistareddy/sentiment_analysis/master/data/test.csv")

# Create feature vectors
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 5,
                             max_df = 0.8,
                             sublinear_tf = True,
                             use_idf = True)

train_vectors = vectorizer.fit_transform(trainData['Content'])
test_vectors = vectorizer.transform(testData['Content'])

def myKernel(x, y) :
    M = np.array 
    

# Perform classification with SVM, kernel=linear
clf = SVM()
t0 = time.time()
classifier_linear = clf.fit(trainData, train_vectors)
t1 = time.time()
prediction_linear = clf.predict(test_vectors)
t2 = time.time()
time_linear_train = t1-t0
time_linear_predict = t2-t1

# results
print("Results for SVC(kernel=linear)")
print("Training time: %fs; Prediction time: %fs" % (time_linear_train, time_linear_predict))
report = classification_report(testData['Label'], prediction_linear, output_dict=True)
print('positive: ', report['pos'])
print('negative: ', report['neg'])
```

Comment: Seeing the error is good, but what good does it do us if we don't know which LINE got the error?

Comment: `fit` and `predict` both take `x` as a parameter, but the functions use `X`.  Are you retyping this code?  The `myKernel` code is wrong, too, but since you don't use it, that's OK.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this error occurs because `TfidfVectorizer.fit_transform` returns [sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html) which doesn't support some operators including <= and >=. You can try to use `.toarray()` method to convert it to NumPy array (e.g. `train_vectors.toarray()`) but I'm not sure if it is suitable for your dataset in terms on memory usage.